# required field for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have added list of `checkbox`es in following way. And I have added required property also. Because user should select at least one checkbox.

```
<div ng-repeat="student in vm.students">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{studentName}}" ng-model="student.selected" name="students" required>
        {{sim.name}}
    </label>
</div>
<div data-ng-messages="userform2.simulations.$error" data-ng-if="vm.interacted(userform2.simulations)" class="error-messages">
    <div data-ng-message="required">You should select atleast one sim.</div>
</div>
```

But this one doesn't work. It works for last checkbox only. If check and uncheck the last one the error message is appear, It doesn't look whether other checkboxes are selected or not.  Any possible way will be highly appreciable.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `But this one doesn't work`? Can you elaborate a bit more on what exactly are you trying to put to work?

Answer (score 0):

In angular you should use ng-required=true to set 'required' on the input

The docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link 
[CheckBox List](http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/)
you will get the answer  ithink you missed checklist -value or you need validation on it for select one check box.
for validation take full list and check every property if any no value is checked then generate a message for it.

I hope it will be help to you